# hyperlink inside chapter / section title

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, chapters

I would like to have the possibility to have a hyperlink inside a chapter / section title.

MWE:

```
 \documentclass[twoside]{book}

 \usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
 \begin{document}
 \chapter{documentation for link to Section 1}
 %%\chapter{documentation for link to \hyperlink{sec1}{Section 1}}

 \hypertarget{sec1}{}\section{Section 1 Reference}

 \hypertarget{sec2}{}\section{Section 2 Reference}
 documentation for \hyperlink{sec1}{Section 1}

 \end{document}
```

This results in the following output:
[image]

We see in section 1.2 the `hyperlink` to section 1.1, but I want to have the link also in the chapter title. When adding a second chapter with a `hyperlink` (remove %% ) I get the error message:

```
Chapter 1.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\<let>-command' on input line 6.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\Hy@reserved@a' on input line 6.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 6.

! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.6 ...on for link to \hyperlink{sec1}{Section 1}}

?
! Emergency stop.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.6 ...on for link to \hyperlink{sec1}{Section 1}}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Question:
How to get the hyperlink in the chapter (/section) title.

Comment: `\chapter{documentation for link to \protect\hyperlink{sec1}{Section 1}}`?

Comment: I'd probably go for `\section{Section 1 Reference}\label{sec1}` instead of `\hypertarget{sec1}{}\section{Section 1 Reference}`. Then one could write `\chapter{documentation for link to \hyperref[sec1]{Section 1}}` (i.e. no `\protect`) because `\hyperref` is robust.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions, I tried them both in a small program and looks like to work (I didn't doubt). In the original code there is already a \label. I have to see what the effect is on a larger project where the documentation is automatically generated, here the fix with `\protect` is, probably, easiest. Maybe you can make an answer of your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `\label`s and then `\hyperref[<label>]{<text>}` for custom text or maybe even `cleveref`'s `\cref`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{documentation for link to \hyperref[sec1]{Section 1}}

\section{Section 1 Reference}\label{sec1}

\section{Section 2 Reference}\label{sec2}
documentation for \hyperref[sec1]{Section 1}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to stick to `\hyperlink` you need to `\protect` it because it is a fragile command.

```
\chapter{documentation for link to \protect\hyperlink{sec1}{Section 1}}
```

You didn't need to protect `\hyperref` in the example above because it is a robust command. See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/35864) for an in-depth explanation of fragile vs. robust commands.

Comment: I've posted a followup question: "TOC / Bookmark and hyperlink inside a chapter / section title" (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434316/toc-bookmark-and-hyperlink-inside-a-chapter-section-title)

Comment: I'd like to add more on @moewe.
To avoid warnings, you can write like below: ```latex
\chapter[documentation for link to Section 1] {documentation for link to \hyperref[sec1]{Section 1}}
```